# Создание простейшей анимированной кнопки в Qt

Tags: python, c++, qt, qpushbutton, qpropertyanimation

Мне совсем не понятен синтаксис `QPropertyAnimation`. Я посмотрел несколько "подобных" вопросов, но так и не разобрался.

Не могли бы вы написать простой пример кнопки, которая по нажатию будет плавно уменьшать свою длину до нуля, чтобы от неё осталась одна иконка, а после повторного нажатия снова возвращалась к прежней длине.

Answer (score 0):

[**Animation Framework**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html) 
Платформа анимации призвана обеспечить простой способ создания анимированных и плавных графических интерфейсов. Анимируя свойства Qt, фреймворк предоставляет большую свободу для анимации виджетов и других объектов QObject. ...

Класс [**QPropertyAnimation**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html) анимирует свойства Qt.

Если использовать *Python* и *PyQt*, то, как вариант, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.btn = QPushButton('click', self)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)                     
        self.btn.resize(100, 100)
        self.btn.move(125, 125)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

    def increase(self):
        rect_start = QRect(self.btn.geometry())
        rect_end = QRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
        rect_end.moveCenter(rect_start.center())

        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.btn, b"geometry", self)
        animation.setStartValue(rect_start)
        animation.setEndValue(rect_end)
        animation.setDuration(1000)
        animation.start(QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    def reduce(self):
        rect_start = QRect(self.btn.geometry())
        rect_end = QRect(0, 0, 50, 50)
        rect_end.moveCenter(rect_start.center())        

        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.btn, b"geometry", self)
        animation.setStartValue(rect_start)
        animation.setEndValue(rect_end)
        animation.setDuration(1000)
        animation.start(QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
        
    def btn_clicked(self, state):
        if state:
            self.reduce()
        else:
            self.increase()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @why что не так?